# Remove #anchor in adressbar when switching tabs with Easy tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, anchor

I'm using [easy tabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) but I don't want it to add an anchor in the end of my address every time I switch a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using your given reference 
i figured out there is configuration to stop updating hash

```
updateHash: false
```

you can do that something like

```
$("#tab-full-container").easytabs({
  animate: true,
  animationSpeed: 1000,
  defaultTab: "span#tab-2",
  panelActiveClass: "active-content-div",
  tabActiveClass: "selected-tab",
  tabs: "> div > span",
  updateHash: false, //make it false <----------------
  cycle: 2000
});
```